# function with parameter return two values

Tags: sql, oracle-apex-5.1

hello stack overflow I have encountered an issue i am trying to create a function which needs parameter that will return two values however I'm having an error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol i dont know where im going wrong if i could get assistance or advice of where im going wrong.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_LOCATIONcname (l_con_id_n in NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER 
IS LOCATION VARCHAR2(30)  CST_NAME VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
SELECT LOCATION, CST_NAME INTO LOCATION FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;
RETURN l_con_id;
END;
```

Comment: As far as I know, anything inside of a function after the line with "return", is ignored. So in this case, "is location" etc would be ignored. Put everything before the line with "return" in it.

Comment: @user770 The `RETURN NUMBER` on line 2 is part of the function specification indicating the data type returned by the function.  It is not the `RETURN` statement that actually returns data.  So no the lines below it are not ignored.

Comment: On line 3 there is a semicolon missing between `LOCATION VARCHAR2(30)` and `CST_NAME VARCHAR2(15);`  Those are two separate variable declarations. Also the `INTO` clause of the select statement is missing `, CST_NAME` between `LOCATION` and `FROM`.  Finally while the query may be selecting data from a table, it's not returning any of that data, instead the return statement is passing out the same `l_con_id` that was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Oracle PL/SQL can only return result value, however, that result value does not need to be an intrinsic/atomic data type, it could be a complex data type such as an array, record, or object data type.

```
create or replace TYPE My_Object_Type as OBJECT (
  location varchar2(30),
  cst_name varchar2(15)
;

create or replace FUNCTION GET_LOCATIONcname (l_con_id_n in NUMBER)
  RETURN My_Object_Type
IS
  My_Result My_Object_Type;
BEGIN
  SELECT My_Object_Type(LOCATION, CST_NAME) INTO My_Result
    FROM LDS_CONSULTANT
   WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = l_con_id;
  RETURN My_Result;
END;
```

Then you can use this function something like this:

```
declare
  My_Result My_Object_Type;
begin
  My_Result := GET_LOCATIONcname(1);
  dbms_output.put_line(My_Result.location||' '||My_Result.cst_name);
end;
```

Comment: You have an error: The function's return type should be `My_Object_Type` and not `NUMBER`.

Comment: Thanks, Fixed. :)